# Adaptable full height of page sidenav

Tags: html, css, nav, stretch, sidenav

I have a simple issue, I've looked through many threads but found no appropriate solution.
I just want to make the background (black) of my sidenav to extend all the way down to the bottom regardless of how much content the page has, a stretchable full page height sidenav (not a fixed one). It only seems to stretch when zooming out but not at 100%, I don't know why is that.

```css
nav {
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';
  height: 70px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: purple;
  position: relative;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 175px;
  float: left;
  color: black;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 10px 0px 8px 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
<nav>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <input id="search-btn" type="checkbox" />
        <label for="search-btn"> </label>
        <input id="search-bar" type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</nav>
<nav class="sidenav">
  <a href="#">Index</a>
  <a href="#">FAQ</a>
  <a href="#">Latest Entries</a>
  <a href="#">Other Sites</a>
</nav>
<div>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet, share your code here then it is not necessary to leave the site.

Comment: Refresh, I can see it the code I posted from codepen here without leaving the site. I think this website just does that by only posting the link.

Comment: I have updated your question with the code from your codepen link.

Comment: i think you should overhaul your code and implement a css-grid system. then simply make the navbar spanning all rows to strech it to the bottom no matter the content

Comment: @tacoshy yeah that's what i am thinking, rewrite code and use flexbox or something to achieve 2 columns layout.

Comment: @tacoshy I made a grid, how do I make the rows stretch to the bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the body as grid by adding `body { display: grid; }`. Next add a 2 column layout by using `grid-template-columns: sidebar-width auto;`. To have at least the entire viewport filled add: `grid-template-rows: navbar-height auto; min-height: 100vh;`.

To have the navbar span both columns you can simply add `grid-column: span 2;`. For better accuracy and not needing to use nth-child selector I added classes to the top navbar aswell as the content div box.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px auto;
  grid-template-rows: 70px auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.nav {
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: purple;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.sidenav {
  color: black;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 10px 0px 8px 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.content {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
<nav class="nav">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <input id="search-btn" type="checkbox">
        <label for="search-btn"> </label>
        <input id="search-bar" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</nav>
<nav class="sidenav">
  <a href="#">Index</a>
  <a href="#">FAQ</a>
  <a href="#">Latest Entries</a>
  <a href="#">Other Sites</a>
</nav>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply place both your `.sidenav` and the div in another div or container, then make that container display flex.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.sidenav {
  width: 175px;
  float: left;
  color: black;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav class="sidenav">
    <a href="#">Index</a>
    <a href="#">FAQ</a>
    <a href="#">Latest Entries</a>
    <a href="#">Other Sites</a>
  </nav>
  <div>
    <br><br><br><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried it, but the result is the same. Also, no height property is stated here.

Comment: when you specify a height property using for the sidenav, it will limit it to the content, in this case, the content in the sidenav. Removing the height for the sidenav makes it fill up the parent div's height.